# how to get foreignkey fields in serializer

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

In serializer, class I am trying to get the category details such as "name" but the following code gives me the foreignkey id

models.py

```
class Category(MP_Node, Timestamps):
    name = models.CharField(_('Name'), max_length=255, db_index=True)


class VideoCategory(Category):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='video_categories', blank=True, null=True, max_length=255)


class VideoCategoryVideo(BaseModel, Timestamps, SoftDelete):
    video = models.ForeignKey(Video, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.ForeignKey(VideoCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

serializers.py

```
class VideoCategoryVideoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = VideoCategoryVideo
        fields = ('category', )

class VideosDetailsListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = Video
        fields = ('id', 'create_date', 'category')

    def get_category(self, data):
        cate = VideoCategoryVideo.objects.filter(video=data.id)
        category = VideoCategoryVideoSerializer(cate, many=True)
        return category.data
```

result is:

```
                "category": [
                    {
                        "category": 1
                    }]
```

but the expected result is

```
   "category": [
                    {
                        "name": "cate_name"
                    }]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `CharField` to `VideoCategoryVideoSerializer` and specify the `source` of the value like this:

```
class VideoCategoryVideoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.CharField(source='category.name', read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = VideoCategoryVideo
        fields = ('category', 'name')
```

This will tell the serializer to get the value for `name` from the related category.